# Loading Resource

Tags: java, resources

I'm coding a Java application which it needs to load some images from a resource folder. I've added that folder to the Java Libraries. 
I make it read the BufferedImages using this code

```
public BufferedImage grabImage(String fileName, int subImgNumber){
    ClassLoader classloader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    BufferedImage tmp;
    if(!fileName.equals("null"))
    try {
        tmp = ImageIO.read(classloader.getResourceAsStream("../res/textures/"+fileName+".png"));
        maxIndex = tmp.getWidth()/32 - 1;
        if(subImgNumber > maxIndex){
            subImgNumber = maxIndex;
        }else if(subImgNumber < 0){
            subImgNumber = 0;
        }
        requestImage = tmp.getSubimage(subImgNumber * 32, 0, 32, 32);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    else
        requestImage = null;
    return requestImage;
}
```

If I test the application in Eclipse it works fine and pretty fast, but when i export the jar file it doesn't work and throw me this exeption

[image: Exeption]

I've checked inside the .jar file and it has all the images i need. Is something wrong with my code?

Comment: Post the rest of the stack trace.

Comment: Probably something goes wrong when reading the image, so `tmp` remains `null`.

Comment: [link](http://imgur.com/Qk66xbA) Here's the image of the complete stack trace, i don't think it would help

Comment: The stack trace tells you where the error took place (file:line). The topmost file that belongs to your source (in this case LevelLoader.java) is where the problem is. The lines above that one indicate that there was a problem reading from the stream. Check the docs for `ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream()` to make sure you are using the method correctly. You should also make sure that the file you are trying to load exists.

Comment: The file exists because I've opened the jar file to check if the resource was in it, and actually there's the images, i've checked the docs before post here and for what I've read it look i didn't make a mistake, actually it work when try the debug in Eclipse itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed,
I've changed the method `getResourceAsStream()` with `getResource()` it fix all the problems